# rails 4 partial extension required under pdf template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, extension-methods, partial

I have using same partial under two different pages.
The first one is under simple `*.html.haml` and the latter under `*.pdf.haml`.

**Example**: I have a partial as views/patient/reports/_invoice.html.haml

*first Usage*:- account.html.haml

`= render partial: 'patient/reports/invoice'`

*second usage*:- under invoice.pdf.haml

`= render partial: 'patient/reports/invoice.html.haml'`

why do I need to provide file extension in the latter one?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the file is a different format so rails is trying to find a partial with the same suffix

i.e. when you type `= render partial: 'patient/reports/invoice'` inside an html file it will look for `patients/reports/invoice.html` however when you are inside a pdf view rails will search for `patients/reports/invoice.pdf`